# java.sql.SQLException: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, websphere-7

I have upgraded my application to `Websphere 7.0`from `Websphere 6.1.` I am using `Microsoft SQL server jdbc driver 4.0` for this application. When i use `sqljdbc4.jar` i get the following error when connecting to database for authentication.

```
  SystemError java.sql.SQLException: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0
```

How to get rid of this.

Comment: Did you try adding older version(JDBC v.3.x) of driver jar file in classpath/lib?

Comment: Jon skeet has answered Your question... You must be lucky one..
Now just mark it as Your answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as per the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC type 4.0 driver system requirements page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx):

> The JDBC driver supports connections to a SQL Azure Database and SQL Server 2005 and later.

It sounds like you're running SQL Server 2000.

Either change driver (e.g. to [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)) or upgrade to a more recent release of SQL Server (which would presumably be a rather bigger task...)

Comment: I have the same issue even though the server version is "9.0.5292" aka 2005.
The connection to my local 2005 server works, but not to a remote machine named "DEVDB1\SQL2005".

Comment: @DaSh: The *exact* same issue? If you're really getting an error message of "SQL Server version 8 is not supported [...]" then that doesn't sound like you're talking to a SQL Server 2005 machine...

Comment: I am 100% sure the instance is 2005.
Could other software, such as OS, have an affect on what JDBC sees/recognizes?

Comment: Actually, I was connecting to wrong instance (wrong port).
Thank you Jon.

Answer (score 2):

You not need change your driver, only your url connection.
Try this:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+SERVER+":"+PORT+";databaseName="+DATABASE+ ";user=" +USER+ ";password=" +PASS+ ";";
```

change for

```
String url ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+SERVER+":"+PORT+";databaseName="+DATABASE+ ";user=" +USER+ ";password=" +PASS+ ";";
```