# java 1.6 and 1.7 to connect to sql server 2000

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i have written a Gui application in java and all is working fine when connecting to SQL 2008 with the jdbc4 API. however i now need to connect to SQL 2000. i have downgraded to jdbc driver 3 but that is incompatible with java 1.6/7 and requires v 1.5 .

is there any way to get the newer versions of java to connect to old SQL 2000.

Comment: If it is a one time thing, try using plain ODBC in order to connect to the old SQL2000. It could also work as a permanent solution, but you would have to pay a small speed penalty.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page. JDBC driver 3.0 with JRE 7 compatibility.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=28562

or have a look at jTDS.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Reading these posts may also help.

[How to make Java work with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310536/how-to-make-java-work-with-sql-server)

[java.sql.SQLException: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732957/java-sql-sqlexception-sql-server-version-8-is-not-supported-by-this-driver-sql)

Comment: Make sure you've placed the jar right, and if it still does not work use ODBC. :-)